# How to know when a ToolWindow is active

Tags: winforms, telerik

I'm trying to figure out how to know when a Telerik's ToolWindow is activated (either by click or keyboard). I have tried the following code but it's not called when the window is activated.

```
    protected override void OnGotFocus(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnGotFocus(e);
        _globalView.ActiveView = this;
    }
```

Has anyone had experience with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following event of RadDock to capture when an window is activated:

```
radDock1.ActiveWindowChanged
```